# Disable steam controller or other controller home button and other non-game inputs for steam games

Tags: steam, linux, controllers

I'm looking for any method (system edit, script, program, option) to disable the Guide button, and all button combinations that Steam intercepts in order to perform non-gaming related tasks, such as all media keys.

I don't know what the controller combos are but you can trigger all the media keys with just a controller. I've witnessed them all: mail, web, stop, play, pause, back, forward, etc. Combinations also open up Big Picture (not in a functional state though), Steam keyboard, and the like, but, obviously, **in the middle of a game absolutely none of these are interesting to me**.

I only want the general in-game controls (moving my character/car, etc.) in-game, as well as outside of a game, because when I'm not playing, I'm not using my controller but a mouse and keyboard.

The idea that I'd **want** to use my controller for desktop tasks should not be assumed, which is what Valve seems to do.

Disabling "Guide button focuses Steam" in the Big Picture controller settings [does not work](https://www.back2gaming.com/guides/disable-home-button-activating-steam-big-picture-mode/#comment-45885). It only prevents that action specifically, and not the rest. And to make matters worse, this option turns itself back on from time to time.

I don't know what the best solution for this would be, because it seems Steam interprets them the wrong way. That's why I'm afraid that this is something that requires modding the Steam app itself.

Any ideas for a simple solution?

Comment: Is this a recent thing? or just steam controllers? I've never had any issue with the xbox controller (for windows). The only button that does anything not game centric is the (X) which brings up the steam overlay. Do these all trigger while you're in game? or you just want the controller to basically be dead when not in game ?

Comment: What is the purpose on that? Can't you just well, like, _not press the Steam guide button_? Check if your desktop configuration is not messed up and maybe restore it to the defaults, if you have issues that should not be happening. You only give us the issue with solution you came up with, but not the real problem here. Seems like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) for me. Also, you know that you can turn the controller off when it's not in use, _riiiight_?

Comment: @Asunez I don't need the sass, so tone it down, the controller turn itself off after 5 minutes of idle so that's not the issue. i cannot not press that button since fingers are flying all over the place and lastly the actions are not limited to the steam guide button, when I disable it in steam it still happens but with other buttons. my desktop is a vanilla. ubuntu this problem is reproducible on an unconfigured fresh ubuntu 19.04 install with just steam added and one game installed from it.

Comment: @Smock i take issue with the in game behavior. the actions I'm getting are not game-related and bring the gaming experience to an abrupt halt. not because the game goes away or minimizes (although sometimes it does minimize), but because I can no longer input to it. This could be a linux only issue although judging from this post (and the willingness to make a windows mod for it) I am not alone in having this issue : steam://openurl/https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/10/412446292772822343/

Comment: Okay, I haven't used SC under Linux environment, so my milage may vary, but I still can't grasp the roots of the issue. The way I use SC is simple - I want to play a game, I add it to Steam (if it's not Steam game), configure the controls for given game, launch & play. After I finish playing I just manually shut the SC down (holding the Steam Guide button does this). You mention that you have the issue when you are using mouse and keyboard, but how does that relate to pressing controller's buttons? Are you using controller on the Ubuntu Desktop? There is a specific configuration for that.

Comment: So you get stuff like mail, web, stop & play happening when you're just pressing A/B/X/Y/Triggers etc? (or a combination of). I've read a [few threads](https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamController/comments/8223os/configuration_any_way_to_disable_desktop/) talking about [disabling desktop](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353370/discussions/0/135507403157722781/) configuration

Comment: @Asunez this is a steam game and i'm talking about rocket league. if I shut down steam it closes the game too.

Comment: @Smock yes, basically.

Comment: Risking suggesting this is an off-topic question: have you tried reinstalling, uninstalling, or updating the drivers for the controller?

Comment: @Joachim it's not. unix stack exchange redirected my question to here specifically. You can't just off topic it off of the whole of stack exchange just because you don't know the answer. this is the best match for this specific question. Your suggestion to resinstall drivers is offtopic as I am on **steam** and **linux** steam installs it's drivers under the hood, they are done best via this automation you cannot get and install them manually also on linux drivers are (for 99.9999% use cases) always automatic never manual. and the problem I have is with steam's "intended" behavior. so....

Comment: Look who's sassy now.. Aside from the weird notion that a *suggestion* to help you fix a problem is off-topic, I'm not talking about Steam drivers (which AFAIK is not a thing). I didn't know that about Linux drivers, though I'm sure manual installations are still perfectly possible. "Intended behaviour" of Steam does not say anything about the real culprit, though, and is not a reason to assume it is on-topic (and, to be clear, I did not suggest it was off-topic, I suggested it could be).

Comment: Do you have another controller you could try, just to get a sense of where the problem might lie?

Comment: steam drivers are very much a thing.